# how to get two Text box/input fields in a single row in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have form where I take user input. I have a ready made template which I am using. But I am unable to get two input fields in a row. I mean first name and last name should be side by side. Might be its simple but I am unable to do this. Kindly help me. Thank you.

Comment: show what you already did (code), please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 ways of doing it in Codeigniter:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo form_label('First Name'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_input(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_label('Last Name'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo form_input(); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or:

```
<?php 
   echo form_label('First Name'); 
   echo ' '.form_input(); 
   echo ' '.form_label('Last Name'); 
   echo ' '.form_input();
```

The `form_input()` methods obviously need to be populated with data like name, id, value and what not.

I suggest taking some online tutorials or buying some books on HTML and CSS. This kind of stuff is also easily found on Google.

Does this answer your question?